# How to buy multiple products in IAP with Auto-renewable subscription for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I have some issue about implement **Auto-renewable subscription** in **iOS**.

In my iOS app, I need to implement **Auto-renewable subscription monthly** of my products in iOS app. Users can purchase **multiple products**. The number of the product is a value that user can **enter manually** from iOS app.

**Ex**: My shop has product ABC. User want to monthly Auto-renewable subscription for 9999 product ABC. 9999 is a number was entered by the user.

Does Apple IAP have support for this case? Thanks

Comment: I am afraid your last question didn't make sense, and this one doesn't, either.

Comment: Does Apple IAP have support for my case? @ElTomato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot set a quantity to an auto renewing subscription.

The quantity option only applies to **consumables** or **non renewing subscriptions** and the limit is 10.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/product/purchaseoption/3749445-quantity

Answer (score 1):

No, a user can only purchase one subscription from a given subscription group at any time. They can cancel, upgrade or downgrade.

You could have different levels of subscription in your subscription group "1 ABC","2 ABC" and so on, but each subscription needs to be a separate product in the subscription group and you have to create them and price them; you can't have the user enter an arbitrary number.

Comment: Hi @Paulw11. So in my case can I use a third-party payment service, eg stripe, PayPal? I think that Apple will reject my app when I submit app to store

Comment: You must use IAP.  You cannot use external payment solutions for products and services delivered in the app.